# Nested Request with JSON

Tags: laravel-5, twilio

I am trying to decode a request that comes from Twilio in Laravel 5.

It comes as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but it has a JSON payload in it with data that I want to access called Memory. 
How do I access it in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As you're looking at memory, I'm guessing you're using [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot). In that case, you should get the `Memory` field from the request and then parse it as JSON data.

```php
$rawMemory = $request->input('Memory');
$memory = json_decode($rawMemory, true);
```

Comment: Awesome! I did this
```$memory = json_decode($request->Memory);```
and I accessed all the data from it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to get the content from the request, which should contain the JSON.

```
$requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
dd($requestData);
```